# XML file using Python

Tags: python, xml

I have made a XML file using python. How can I retrieve an element from it? Will you help me with the code?

Also I need to have my output (i.e. element of each attribute come in separate lines in that particular XML file).

Comment: Please provide a sample of the XML you've got and what data you want to extract from it

Answer (score 0):

Python comes with 2 modules for xml processing [mindom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) which is a DOM implemetation and the more 'pythonic' [Element Tree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) which has [other information and links to examples etc](http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm) I use a third party library [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) which is in effect a super set of Element Tree

Answer (score 0):

There is also the excellent [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/index.html) library. You can query the tree with [xpath](http://codespeak.net/lxml/xpathxslt.html) or if you are familiar with css you can select elements with [cssselect](http://codespeak.net/lxml/cssselect.html).

```
In [1]: from lxml import etree
In [2]: from StringIO import StringIO
In [3]: f = StringIO('<foo><bar id="1">hello</bar><bar id="2">world</bar></foo>')
In [4]: tree = etree.parse(f)
In [5]: r = tree.xpath('/foo/bar')
In [6]: print len(r)
2
In [7]: for elem in r:
   ....:     print elem.get('id'), elem.text   
1 hello
2 world
```